# How to do transaction control on data access using DataAdapter and Stored Procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, dataadapter

How to do transaction control on data access using DataAdapter and Stored Procedure in C#? Currently I want to execute 2 stored procedure calls via DataAdapter, but I want to do transaction control on it. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The preferred way of doing so is to use transaction scopes to handle this for you.** Just surround the body of code that invoke both stored procedure calls with a new  [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28VS.90%29.aspx):

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  // your ADO.NET code that calls sprocs ...
}
```

Any calls to the database that occur on the same connection will automatically be combined into a single transaction. You can also specify whether the code within the transaction scope should enlist in an existing transaction or start its own via the optional  [`TransactionScopeOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeoption.aspx) parameter.

This is the preferred manner of combining calls into a single transaction. The [alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971557.aspx), is to manually acquire a DBTransaction by calling [`Connection.BeginTransaction()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t92b7dt5.aspx) - performing your work and then calling `tran.Commit()`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the easiest way to do this would be to wrap both calls in a TransactionScope.  See the example on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx